# Авторизация из контроллера Spring Security

Tags: spring, авторизация

Добрый день

Kак можно произвести авторизацию из моего контроллера в Spring? нужно слать редирект на "j spring security check" или это можно как то сделать по другому?

UPD пример решения

[Тыц](http://mrather.blogspot.com/2010/02/extending-usernamepasswordauthenticatio.html)

[Тыц](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/recaptcha-login-form-with-spring-security/)

Comment: как одно из решений наследуетесь от класса "UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter", задаете своему фильтру точку входа, получаете доступ к методам с успешной или не успешной авторизации, а также можете выполнить проверку до начала авторизации

еще есть такие обработчики которые реагируют на успешное или не успешное завершение аутентификации "AuthenticationSuccessHandler" и "AuthenticationFailureHandler" их можно перекрыть и указать в конфиге. А для того чтобы отловить проверку можно повесить фильтр перед "FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" унаследовавшись от "OncePerRequestFilter"

Comment: @Lookingfor, как по мне, идеальный вариант, все работает и элегантно выглядит) Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код из исходников фильтра для аутентификации **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter**

получение authentication метод **attemptAuthentication**

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
setDetails(request, authRequest);
return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
```

далее игнорируя вызов разных эвентов при удачном исходе в методе **successfulAuthentication** класса **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter** от которого наследуется предыдущий класс

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Обобщая все выше сказанное

1. Создаете auth request
2. Прогоняете его через **AuthenticationManager**, предварительно описав его в конфигурации
3. Если все хорошо то записаваете результат в контекст

Остальное зависит от ваших целей, помимо всего этого можно создавать свои фильтры для аутентификации, есть там еще специальные handler - ы для успешной или не успешной аутентификации в общем тонкостей много, поэтому советую посмотреть код исходников приведенных классов, там ничего сложного нет

Comment: копание в исходниках очень веселая задача)
если не секрет, можно узнать сколько вам лет?)
просто интерестно, сколько нужно потратить времени, что бы хорошо понимать что к чему в Спринге

Comment: Так уж сложилось, что компании в которых я работал использовали самописные фреймворки/библиотеки для создания своих продуктов, и поверьте мне рано или поздно становится все тяжелее и тяжелее поддерживать такой, код) поэтом где-то год назад я начал изучать спринг, если у вас есть опыт разработки и неплохие знания java, понимание MVC и других паттернов) то спринг достаточно легко изучается и мне очень нравится его концепция, а также множество возможностей. Помимо этого огромное сообщество, множество уроков, и много форумов с ответами на вопросы. Советую книжку "Spring in action" есть на русском

Comment: @Lookingfor, в security xml есть он.

   <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
 </security:authentication-manager>

Comment: Как то так

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

Comment: @Lookingfor, а такой вопрос
мне кажется что делать это в контроллере это какой то кастыльный метод
  Может есть какой то фильтр, что то на подобе pre authorization?

Comment: Да есть, но как я уже говорил все зависит от задачи!

К примеру у меня была задача авторизации по токену, притом надо было сделать так что если по истечению времени сессия на сервере грохнулась, а пользователь выполнил комманду, то нужно было его автоматом залогинить, и плюс ко всему выполнить нужную комманду, для ее решения я использовал фильтр.

Comment: И еще все логику работы лучше выносить в отдельные классы-бины, а в контроллере только вызывать эту логику, создание дополнительного слоя даст вам определенную гибкость в разработке и в дальнейшем поддержке системы.

Comment: @Lookingfor
может ты помнишь, я недавно про капчу на форуме спрашивал, и ты отвечал
так это и есть продолжение этой задачи. я хочу сразу после проверки капчи сделать авторизацию, но что то не особо получается)
а то если эти 2 метода разделить, то что мешает боту тупо игнорить капчу и стучатся на j_spring_security_check напрямую?) вот и пытаюсь эти 2 метода скрутить

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать следующим образом:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password)
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Comment: а я сам должен вызывать методы onAuthenticationSuccess и AuthenticationFailure?